# Unable to connect to MongoDB Replica Set from other server using robo3T and in C#

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have installed mongodb Replica Set, in the file ***mongod.conf*** has added BIND_IP as below

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1, 100.0.192.68
```

When I use robo3t to connect the "replica set" type the error, but when connected to the "Direct Connection" is successful.

> error TYPE="Replica Set

[image]

Connection string C# `"mongodb://100.0.192.68:27017,100.0.192.68:27017/databasename?safe=true&connect=replicaSet&replicaSet=r0"`

Comment: Were you able to solve it ? I am also facing same issue

Comment: I experience a similar problem. Linux is running my mongodb replication set. Using Robo 3T to connect from Windows 10 to the Linux replication set fails with "authentication failed". Testing the connection leads to "No chance to authorize". Mongodb is configured to authorization enabled and the user account has been created. Locally on the Linux server is can connect to the server with mongo -u username -p password.

Comment: This looks a private IP , you might need to put SSH host server details in SSH section and also robo3T doesn't support replicaset over SSH , thus select "Direct Connection" in type option in "Connection" tab

Answer (score 0):

Robo 3T seems to have problems to access replica sets with authenticated connections via "Authentication". Better activate the ssh-server on all members of the replication set. Then in Robo 3T you add all members to the connection and **select ssh** with auth method password. This way I was able to get around this limitation.

Comment: what about security in production. SSH tunnel is helpful

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was too short timeout (default `10 seconds`) in Robo3T. To increase the timeout, I had to modify `mongoTimeoutSec` property in `robo3t.json` config file.

Depending on your OS, you can find `robo3t.json` config file in:

```
Windows
    C:\Users\<user>\.3T\robo-3t\1.1.1\robo3t.json

MAC
    /Users/<user>/.3T/robo-3t/1.1.1/robo3t.json

Linux
    /home/<user>/.3T/robo-3t/1.1.1/robo3t.json
```

**Before modifying `robo3t.json` close Robo3T itself.**

In this file, modify timeout to your needs:

```
"mongoTimeoutSec" : 30,
```

After this modification, save the file and start Robo3T.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was that I had used hostnames to setup replica set while using IPs in connection string and in Robo 3T conn settings.

After adding hostnames to my win10's hosts file (for POC), I could connect from Win10/C# and Win10/Robo 3T using hostnames instead of IPs to my replica set on Linux.