# Robomongo: Cannot connect to replica set. Set's primary is unreachable

Tags: mongodb, heroku, mlab, mongodb-atlas, robo3t

I'm migrating mLab from Heroku to MongoDB Atlas. As one of steps I want to check if there is a connectivity to newly created cluster. I'm used [Robo3T](https://robomongo.org/download) (formerly Robomongo) for Heroku mLab instances. But it doesn't work with Atlas. I'm getting following error when creating connection from URL:

```
Cannot connect to replica set "SampleProject"[cluster-abcd12ef-shard-00-00.a0b1c.mongodb.net:27017]. 
Set's primary is unreachable.

Reason:
Failed to initialize MongoWorker. Reason: connect failed
```

Tried to adjust settings, but everything looks correct there, like for Heroku, the only host and port are different.

Also looked on [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60984891/unable-to-connect-to-mongo-replica-sets-using-robo3t) and on [GitHub isssues](https://github.com/Studio3T/robomongo/issues/) but nothing helped.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

First of all, check if you are using latest Robo3T. MongoDB Atlas uses `mongodb+srv://` protocol, that was not supported some time before.

After that please go by following check-list:

- Use import `From SRV` by copy-pasting URL from MongoDB Atlas;
- MongoDB Atlas is using Replica Sets even for free Sandbox (Atlas M0) accounts. So during creation ensure that you used that type;
- Fill or check all cluster members;
- `Set Name` should be set.

**important differences** on Authentication tab:

- `Database` should be `admin` not like database name (used on Heroku),
- `Auth Mechanism` should be `SCRAM-SHA-1`
- Check `Manually specify visible databases` and type there `admin,<you database name from Heroku>`

on TLS tab:

- Check `Use TLS protocol`
- `Authentication method` - `Self-signed Certificate`

Now it should work.

**P.S.** Previously, I also had problems with having database same like on Heroku with same db-name and user-name, also I thought that Auth Mechanism should be MONGODB-CR. But that didn't work.

**P.P.S.** If you don't see `Manually specify visible databases` - then please check if you have the latest version (1.4.+) of Robo3T (previously known as Robomongo)

Comment: Just downloaded on Mac & Windows. Mac works and Windoes does not. Confirmed all inputs/form fields match the "answer". Windows Build is Robo 3T 1.4.3 (Build 48f7dfde - 3/2021). Sometimes I get the error as stated in orignal thread other times the app just crashes unexpectedly.

Comment: @Greg, worked for me on 1.4.1. And for later versions I see [issues on GitHub](https://github.com/Studio3T/robomongo/issues). You can try to also use 1.4.1. BTW, where your MongoDB is hosting?

Comment: Amazing. Details are just perfect. Didn't find it anywhere else. Thank you somuch

Comment: After "import from URI" i had to go and set the certificate to "Self-signed Certificate" that was what did the trick for me!

Answer (score 9):

If anyone getting this error while using Robo3T version `1.4.4`, we can resolve this issue by update `robo3t.json` file (enable logs and you can see where this file localed)

> By enable Logs, you will see where settings saved via message starts with `Info: Settings saved to: {robo3t.json_path}`

- Paste your URI as normal, then click `From URI` as normal, then Save.
- Close Robo3T (important)
- Open `robo3t.json` file using some text editor.
- Inside `connections` scope, lookup your connection just created from step above, find `allowInvalidCertificates` property inside `ssl` object, change value from `false` to `true` then save the file
- Open Robo3T then connect to the connection, it should connect normally

Comment: Thanks, bro!
You saved a few hours of work for me

Comment: For those who wonder how to enable logs, in the top left corner, near `File` there is `View`. Click on that and you can find a checkbox for logs. Enable that checkbox and you will find a dialogue box opens at the bottom of applications with logs. Scroll up in that logs and you can find the path to `robo3T.json`.

Comment: We can also use `Ctrl+L` to open logs.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you have whitelisted your IP address on mongodb cloud portal under `Network Access`.

Comment: using DigitalOcean Mongodb cluster manged service, this seems crucial step + specify a 'self-signed ' certificate type on TLS tab without the need to

Answer (score 1):

#### Check your username and password!

##### tl;dr

It seems Robo 3T 1.4.3 returns the `Cannot connect to replica set... Set's primary is unreachable` error also for authentication errors. Double check your user credentials.

##### Details

In the past, all the above excellent answers have helped me resolve this error message. However, recently I encountered an Atlas cluster that seemed immune to all workarounds. I finally gave up and tried with the "official" MongoDB Compass client that Atlas promotes. This client also returned an error, but a different and far more useful one:

> bad auth : Authentication failed.

Suspecting an incorrect password, I generated a new password for the user in Atlas and updated it in Robo 3T. After this Robo successfully connected to the DB.

Answer (score 1):

After doing import "From URI" i had to go TLS -> "Authentication Method" and select "Self-signed Certificate".

I didn't have the same problem when connecting from the MongoDB extension on VSCode.

Answer (score 0):

For me I needed to go into the Edit section of the Connection:

[image]

Then under the Authentication tab:

[image]

Paste my password into the password input:

[image: password input]

The passwords in my json files were encrypted, so I needed the unencrypted password directly from Atlas